# Does editing Meta posts count toward the editing badges?

Tags: support, meta, badges

Just curious: Does editing meta posts count toward any of the editing-related badges, or do the badges only take [scifi.stackexchange.com](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) posts into consideration?
. 
I did check to see if this question had already been asked, but didn't find it. If it *has* already been asked and answered, please point me that way!

Comment: It might have been asked on MSO, but not here I don't think

Answer (score 7):

Per-site Metas have [their own badges](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/badges), so editing things *does* earn badges, but they're not Main site badges.

Answer (score 6):

For badge purposes, the Meta and Main sites are separate (with the exception of [quorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/62/quorum) and [convention](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/63/convention)). So editing meta posts counts towards the badge for the meta site, but not the main badge.